# how to create neo4j embedded rest server on web hosting platforms

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am using neo4j with spring data in my spring mvc application. Ccurrently I am in dev environment and have configured neo4j as an embedded server.Now due to some reason multiple applications will be using this db so I have configured neo4j as embedded rest server running as a single application.

So in all the client applications I pass `http://localhost:7474/db/data/` to the `org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase` class as instructed in `https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/02/spring-data-neo4j/` . Can I use this kind of setup on web hosting platform say mochahost.com because this setup needs port number and I guess I will not be allowed to use port in this fashion? Also if it is not possible, is there any alternative to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can use outgoing ports. For hosting your cloud database you might want to look at http://graphenedb.com

One word of caution though. SDN over REST is not yet optimized and will not provide the same performance as the embedded server.

You should try to mostly use repositories with cypher statements that return simple data mapped with `@MapResult` or `@QueryResult`

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply. Will surely keep in mind the suggestion about optimization. But do you mean to say that i can use this kind of setup on any java hosting service or only on cloud database hosting like graphenedb and heroku?